# Creating a queryable table from Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am looking to add a page where users can look up questions on my site in a similar way as done by [Leetcode (screenshot attached to this link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT8Ps.png). What would be the most efficient way to do this in Firestore db so that I don't constantly need to re-read data from firebase when a user decides to sort by another parameter? For example, I would need to run a query to sort by one question type and then I would need to run another query to sort by date posted. Is there a way to make this more efficient rather than reading all the data at once and doing the query client-side?

Comment: Turn on persistence so you get documents once.

Comment: @Mises I'm not really sure what that is. Does that mean that I would need to read the entire collection of questions? Because I can see that becoming a problem if I have 1000 questions (i.e. 1000 reads every time a user wants to choose a question).

Comment: Persistence in Firestore let you keep files in browser storage, so you can access them offline and if you use `onSnapshot()` listener it will only read files once unless they were updated.